# Specify effect size in simulated data

Tags: r, simulation

I'm using the `simstudy` package to create simulated data sets for a power analysis of a mixed effects model (using `lmer`). What I would like to do is to be able to simulate a specific effect size for each group in the simulated data for the dependent/outcome variable. What I'm trying to do is set an r value for each group in the simulated data set across each time point.

Here's a sample data frame that I generated using `simstudy`

```
cid period  Group   male    time
1   0   3   1   0
1   1   3   1   3
1   2   3   1   6
1   3   3   1   9
1   4   3   1   25
2   0   1   1   0
2   1   1   1   3
2   2   1   1   6
2   3   1   1   9
2   4   1   1   25
3   0   1   0   0
3   1   1   0   3
3   2   1   0   6
3   3   1   0   9
3   4   1   0   25
4   0   1   1   0
4   1   1   1   3
4   2   1   1   6
4   3   1   1   9
4   4   1   1   25
5   0   3   0   0
5   1   3   0   3
5   2   3   0   6
5   3   3   0   9
5   4   3   0   25
6   0   1   1   0
6   1   1   1   3
6   2   1   1   6
6   3   1   1   9
6   4   1   1   25
7   0   3   0   0
7   1   3   0   3
7   2   3   0   6
7   3   3   0   9
7   4   3   0   25
8   0   2   1   0
8   1   2   1   3
8   2   2   1   6
8   3   2   1   9
8   4   2   1   25
9   0   3   1   0
9   1   3   1   3
9   2   3   1   6
9   3   3   1   9
9   4   3   1   25
10  0   3   1   0
10  1   3   1   3
10  2   3   1   6
10  3   3   1   9
10  4   3   1   25
```

Let's assume a variable y with a mean = 25 and an SD = 10. Then assume an r for group 1 = .2, group 2 = .5, group 3 = .8
How would I simulate a variable (y) that has those properties? I was thinking something along the lines of rnorm, but really not having a lot of success.

~Note that `simstudy` provides a formula module to define the outcome variable - it takes the form of

```
#define the column variable
  def <- defData(def, varname = "small.eff", dist = "normal", formula = 0.3)
#define the values for the column
    dtAdd <- defDataAdd(varname = "PRCA.small", dist = "normal", formula = 
"25  - (Group + 1) * (period * small.eff)", variance = 10)
```

But I couldn't figure out how to actually create standardized variables in the formula space that would allow me to set a concrete r value for each group.